# Mocha testing: faking a method

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

### Problem

I have the following javascript file I want to test:

```
function myLocalHouse() {
     this.init = function() {
        $.post(//Ajax call using jQuery);
     };

     this.buyHouse(money, date) {
       //code I want to test with mocha
     };

     this.init();
};
```

As you can see, the `init` method uses jQuery, and when I execute `mocha` in a console, to test it, fails as it doesn't find the `$` object.

So my solution was to override and fake the `init` method. The problem is that my attemps to do that have failed miserably. So sad.

### What I have tried

This is my test that tries to test `myLocalHouse` and my three attemps to override the init method to use an empty function instead.

```
   var myLocalHouse = require('./myLocalHouse.js').myLocalHouse;

   suite('houses suite', function() {
      test('test that buy House works correctly', function() {
         //First attemp at overriding init method: FAILED
         myLocalHouse.prototype.init = function() {};

         //Second attemp at overriding init method: FAILED
         myLocalHouse.__proto__.init = function() {};

         var myLocalHouseInstance = new myLocalHouse();

         //Third attemp at overriding init method: FAILED
         myLocalHouseInstance.prototype.init = function() {};

         var something = myLocalHouseInstance.buyHouse(100, '17/08/2013');
      });
   });
```

I just...I don't know how to overriding the `init` method.

I'm doing something wrong? Is there another way to do the same thing?

Comment: Your `init` method is not defined on the prototype chain. Unless you've got a very good reason to create the method at runtime, move the `init` method to its prototype.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the problem is that `myLocalHouse` function/class/object/whatever is legacy code. And is **horrendously big**, intensively used in several files in the application, so changing the way it works, maybe breaks something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to modify anything at all in the legacy code, the following method can be used:

```
function myTestHouse() {
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'init', {
        set: function() { /* Ignore setter */ },
        get: function() { return function() { /* dummy*/}; },
        enumerable: true
    });
    var _this = myLocalHouse.apply(this, arguments);
    return _this || this;
};
myTestHouse.prototype = myLocalHouse.prototype;

// Usage
var myLocalHouseInstance = new myTestHouse();
```

Using [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), I define a read-only method that silently ignores setters. After that, I call the original constructor (`myLocalTestHouse`) using [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

Note: This method is fully transparent. The created instance behaves as if you were invoking the original constructor.